# Bug in reduce from purrr in R?

Tags: r, purrr

In order to produce a markdown document with some strucure like

```
"Name and ID: %s Authors: %s Date of revision: %s"?
```

and looped over

I tried

```
reduce(as.list(letters[1:3]),sprintf,fmt="%s %s %s")
```

which doesn't work, it throws the error

```
Error in fn(out, elt, ...) : too few arguments
```

I expected

```
[1] "a b c"
```

since

```
reduce(as.list(letters[1:2]),sprintf,fmt="%s %s")
```

works and outputs

```
[1] "a b"
```

```
> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
\[1\] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
\[4\] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8

time zone: Europe/Paris
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
\[1\] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
\[1\] purrr_1.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
\[1\] compiler_4.3.2    magrittr_2.0.3    cli_3.6.2         tools_4.3.2       rstudioapi_0.15.0 vctrs_0.6.5       lifecycle_1.0.4   rlang_1.1.3

>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `reduce` is needed you could achieve your desired result by using `fmt="%s %s"`:

```r
library(purrr)

reduce(
  as.list(letters[1:3]),
  sprintf,
  fmt = "%s %s"
)
#> [1] "a b c"
```

From the docs (`?purrr::reduce`) the function `.f` should be

> ... a 2-argument function. The function will be passed the accumulated value as the first argument and the "next" value as the second argument.

Hence, for your example `reduce` will pass two arguments to `sprintf`, the first is the accumulated value from the previous step and the second argument is the next value from your list of letters. But as you specified a format string with 3 arguments you get an error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you used `reduce` in a right way, but you can try the solutions for example as below

```
> x <- as.list(letters[1:3])

> reduce(x, paste)
[1] "a b c"

> do.call(paste, x)
[1] "a b c"
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the function passed to `reduce` must take in two inputs. To do what you want using reduce, you could have:

```
reduce(letters[1:4], ~sprintf("%s %s", .x, .y))
[1] "a b c d"
```

---

think of it as:

```
 sprintf('%s %s', sprintf('%s %s', 'a', 'b'), 'c')
```

Please read more on `reduce`. Try writing the code using `for-loop` and see whether you understand the logic. That will simplify the task.

---

Perharps your goal could be achieved using a simpler version:

```
 exec(sprintf, '%s %s %s', !!!letters[1:3])
```

Comment: Ok, I probably used the wrong tool

Answer (score 2):

If you type in ??reduce you will see that will purr:

```
"reduce() is an operation that combines the elements of a vector into a single value. The combination is driven by .f, a binary function that takes two values and returns a single value:"
```

So reduce can't work because it expects 2 values where you used 3. You could try another approach:

```
paste(letters[1:3], collapse = " ")
```

Comment: IDK why i get downvoted. I answered the question correctly (before the edits to the question were made).

Comment: +1 from me. I expected a procedure called reduce to take more arguments from other languages. Maybe it's just badly named

Comment: I think the OP's main question is how to make `reduce` work to paste a list of strings. You propose another answer and assert that `reduce` cannot work in this issue. Actually `reduce` works perfectly like Stefan's answer.